# Cannot view simple website hosted on an EC2 server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, webserver

I'm having a real brain fart and cannot create a simple ec2 server which will serve up even the default index.html of apache2 or httpd (tried multiple linux types). I've tried at least four different configurations, all creating an ec2 instance (aws Linux 2, Ubuntu, etc) and adding the http and https rules setting the input from to 0.0.0.0/0 for port 80 and 443 at least.

I've then ssh'd in and installed either apache2 or httpd (depending on the ec2 instance I've launched) and made sure that the service is running and that there's an index.html in /var/www/html but cannot get the server to serve it up. Also checked firewall settings on the instance itself to make sure 80 and 443 aren't blocked.

Anybody had similar and then figured what, probable simple step, they were missing. I've even resorted to following a couple of tutorials and the aws steps to double check I'm not doing anything wrong. I'm doing exactly what the tutorials say, even creating a VPC with public access for belts and braces, but cannot figure it.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: I would start by running something like `curl http://localhost` on the EC2 server itself to make sure apache is running and serving something. How are you trying to connect to the server in your web browser? Are you using the server's public IP or public DNS name?

Comment: Is the dns pointed correctly?

Comment: I've tried with both the public ip as provided by aws control panels, and the public IPv4 DNS, also from the control panel.

Comment: curl localhost responds with a html doc

Comment: ```curl localhost responds with a html doc``` then it's a network configuration problem, or firewall problem

Comment: You don't have any Network ACL rules configured in your VPC do you?

Comment: I would look at using https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Comment: Mark B I’ve tried with and without a vpc, I’m new to aws and have previously only used physical hardware where I’d have more control. I really want to get my head into aws but this stumbling block has stumped me. 

I can ssh into the server using the .pem file, and I included port 80 in the security policy at the same place I set up port 22 so I just don’t understand why the http request is timing out but not the ssh request